# Laravel join table with null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to join 2 table with specific data, like **supplyments** where id is **1** but get all data from the other table. I test it with this code and success but when **id is not 1 but not null** in **supplyments** data from other table not show. From that output as you can see id 3 in supply_categories not showed because id is not 1 but not null too

```
$this->hasMany(Supplyment::class, 'id_user')
     ->rightJoin('supply_categories as category', 'category.id', '=', 'supplyments.id_category')
     ->orWhereNull('supplyments.id_user');
```

**Output**

```
"supplyment": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "egg",
            "id_user": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "glass",
            "id_user": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "table",
            "id_user": null
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Use join only rather than right join.

Comment: but i want get all data from other table
so i can see data that has not been retrieved with that which has been retrieved @Tayyabmehar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to get all supplements:

```
Supplyment::all(); // all items include null iser_ids
Supplyment::has('user'); // all items except user_id = null
Supplyment::doesntHave('user'); // all items with user_id = null
```

But, if you want to get supplements from a user instance, you can define a function inside the user model to get all supplements as below (not recommended because it is confusing):

```php
public function allSupplements() {
    return Supplyment::query();
}
```

Then you may use it like:

```
$user->allSupplements()->where('name', $name)->get()
```

or simply:

```
$user->allSupplements()->get()
```

And if you need `$user->allSupplements;` define an attribute getter:

```php
public function getAllSupplementsAttribute() {
    return $this->allSupplements()->get();
}
```